# Invoking boolean methods

Tags: methods, boolean, geometry, invoke

I'm trying to figure out how to invoke a Boolean method as true or false. Here is what I have thus far:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
public class AssignmentThree {

public static void main(String[]args) {


    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("Enter the length of Edge 1: ");
    double edge1 = scan.nextDouble();
    System.out.print("Enter the length of Edge 2: ");
    double edge2 = scan.nextDouble();
    System.out.print("Enter the length of Edge 3: ");
    double edge3 = scan.nextDouble();
    scan.close();

    DecimalFormat Dec = new DecimalFormat("###,###,##0.00");
    if(isValid (edge1, edge2, edge3) == true) {
        System.out.println("The area of the triangle is " + Dec.format(area(edge1, edge2, edge3)));
    }
    if(isValid (edge1, edge2, edge3) == false) {
        System.out.println("This is not a valid traingle");
    }
}   

public static boolean isValid(double side1, double side2, double side3) {

    //testing to see if the triangle is real
    if(side1+side2>side3 || side1+side3>side2 || side2+side3>side1) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

I'm not sure if the problem is in my method or not but when the program is ran it simply prints the area, and never if its valid or not.

Comment: One code improvement hint: Whenever you have code like "if xxx return true else return false", and you're not being paid per size of source code files, you could make it just "return xxx".

Comment: Have you stepped through this with a debugger?   Or at least, print out the values of the three sides after they've been inputted in main(), and also from inside isValid(), to make sure it's getting what you think you're giving it.

Comment: Another hint (this is the most important): could the second "if" in main() be replaced by an "else", making it belong to the first "if"?

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! As far as debugging goes, I looked at it for a few and couldn't figure anything out. Tried moving things around and replacing the if with an else and it just gives me a syntax error.

Comment: Figured it out. Changed my isValid if statement to have && isntead of ||. Thanks for the help Daren!